# Multer - req.file is always undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer

Say I have the following Schema:

```
let personSchema = new Schema({
    personData: {
        image: { type: String },
        basicInformation: [{
            firstName: { type: String },
            surname: { type: String },
            email: { type: String },
            phone: { type: String },
        }],
    }
})
```

How could I save this to the database? Currently I got a post route `/new`. In that route I make a new person to store in the DB:

```
const person = new Person({
        personData: {
            image: req.body.personData.file.path,
            basicInformation: req.body.personData.basicInformation,
            profile: req.body.personData.profile,
            experience: req.body.personData.experience,
            education: req.body.personData.education,
            skills: req.body.personData.skills,
            hobbies: req.body.personData.hobbies
        }
    });
```

The problem is this line:

```
image: req.body.personData.file.path,
```

`req.file` will now (as far as I know) forever be undefined because file is not defined inside req object. It is defined in req.body object.

------------- *** EDIT *** -------------

Asked to provide upload code, so here it goes: 
The below code works fine. To test things out I started with an image model with just one field for the image. Then on the frontend, appending that image to `FormData` and sending it to `/upload` like this:

```
await axios.post(urlImage, formData, {
                        headers: {
                            "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
                        }
                    });
```

```
personRoutes.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('BODY: ', req.body.file)
    console.log('REQ.FILE.PATH: ', req.file)

    const image = new Image({
            file: req.file.path,
    });
    image.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('YES', result)
            res.redirect('/projects')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('KUT', err)
        })
});
```

So again, the above code is all good, works like a charm. However, what if I wanted to store MORE than just ONE image, like a firstname, lastname, etc. That's where things get tricky for me, because simply appending the image to a `FormData` object and sending that won't suffice anymore. I'd have to send an object with the `image`, `firstname`, and `lastname` fields. So my post route would look something like:

```
personRoutes.post('/new', (req, res) => {
    const person = new Person({
        personData: {
            image: req.body.personData.file.path,
            basicInformation: req.body.personData.basicInformation,
            profile: req.body.personData.profile,
            experience: req.body.personData.experience,
            education: req.body.personData.education,
            skills: req.body.personData.skills,
            hobbies: req.body.personData.hobbies
        }
    });
    person.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('YES', result)
            res.redirect('/projects')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('KUT', err)
        })
});
```

And on my frontend I'd have to do something like this:

```
let testObj = {
                    file: this.person.personData.image,
                    firstname: "Reinier",
                    lastname: "Galien"
                }

                const formData2 = new FormData();
                formData2.append('file', testObj)
```

And send that with axios, the problem being that the `file` now lives inside `req.body`.

Comment: Can you post your upload middleware or code ? Also if you're access a file it should just be `req.file.imageUrl ` .  Need a bit more code to assist you

Comment: Hi O'Dane Brissett. Thank you very much for taking the time to comment on my post. I've added more information to the post. Like you state in your answer, a file should be accessible with ```req.file.imageUrl```, but what if the image is inside ```req.body```? Anyway I really really appreciate it if you can take some time to look at this, I don't know what to do anymore lel. I also got a git repo here: github.com/Mertakus/MEVN_APP .

Comment: You don't have to structure the person Object like that. Also, the file path would be here req.file.path.